# sum up multiple columns using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have three columns and i would like to sum it up but i am not getting sum but i get only nan value in the result column after trying these codes below. Not sure if it is caused because of more NAN values. I have negative, positive, Zero and NAN values in the columns.

The tried codes are:

```
df['Prev15Volatility'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['one'] + x['two'] + x['three'], axis=1)


df['Prev15Volatility'] = df['one'] + df['two'] + df['three']
```

The table looks like this

```
One        Two    Three   
0.916377   NAN     NAN     
NAN        -19.0   NAN
```

Expected

```
One        Two    Three   Result
0.916377   NAN     NAN     0.916
NAN        -19.0   NAN     -19.0
```

Comment: `df['Result'] = df['one'] + df['two'] + df['three']`?

Comment: Just use `df.sum(axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Prev15Volatility'] = df[['one', 'two', 'three']].transform(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(axis=1)
```

`pd.to_numeric` is in there because those "NAN" values look strange. If they *are* in fact `nan`, you can take that out.

Comment: Cool, Works fine :) Ty. But i don't want to remove NAN. Just keep it the way it is.

Comment: @KSp That doesn't *remove* `nan` values. What I mean is that your sample data shows something that looks like the *string* `'NAN'`, not the *special value* `nan`. If it's the former, then taking the sum without first converting to numeric will just concatenate strings, instead of performing the arithmetic sum, like you want.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for your explanation. I just now understood why it gave NAN when i added.